# 03 chevy impala- I have a bad misfire

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, ignition, misfire

When I push on the gas it hesitates to go. The check engine light starts flashing but once it gets rolling its gone.

I change the spark plugs, put in a gas treatment, shot some B-12 in it and changed the air filter.

Its still doing.

Could you help figure out what the problem is?

Comment: What kind of car do you have?  Can you type in the year, the manufacturer and the model please?  Also, what is the mist?  Can You explain the mist?

Comment: @DucatiKiller I'm guessing that should have been miss, not mist. But you never know.

Comment: @HandyHowie  I think your right.  I mist it.

Comment: It is an 03 chevy impala and yeah I meant miss